# XLST Split Node List Grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

Im using XSLT 1.0. Is there a way to split a set of nodes using a delimiter, split them into groups, and then get the count of the group with most nodes?

My XML is structured as:

```
<Tree>
  <Leaf>
    <Label>Leaf 1</Label>
  </Leaf>
  <Leaf>
    <Label>Leaf 2</Label>
  </Leaf>
  <Leaf>
    <Label>Leaf 3</Label>
  </Leaf>
  <Break />
  <Trunk>
    <Label>Trunk 1</Label>
  </Trunk>
  <Leaf>
    <Label>Leaf 5</Label>
  </Leaf>
  <Stem>
    <Label>Stem 1</Label>
  </Stem>
  <Stem>
    <Label>Stem 2</Label>
  </Stem>
  <Stem>
    <Label>Stem 3</Label>
  </Stem>
  <Break />
  <Trunk>
    <Label>Trunk 2</Label>
  </Trunk>
  <Leaf>
    <Label>Leaf 6</Label>
  </Leaf>
  <Break />
  <Stem>
    <Label>Stem 4 </Label>
  </Stem>
</Tree>
```

EDIT: My delimiter is the `<Break />` node. There can be many `<Break />` inside my list. So based on the above XML, the expected groupings are as follows:

> 1st set (Count = 3): Leaf 1, Leaf 2, and Leaf 3
>
> 2nd set (Count = 5): Trunk 1, Leaf 5, Stem 1, Stem 2, Stem 3
>
> 3rd set (Count = 2): Trunk 2, Leaf 6
>
> 4th set (Count = 1): Stem 4

Expected Output: "5" because it is the highest count among the sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with grouping in XSLT 1.0, you need to use a technique called "[Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)"

In your case, one way to define the group is by counting the number of preceding `Break` elements

```
<xsl:key name="groups" match="Tree/*[not(self::Break)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::Break)" />
```

Then to get each group, you do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::Break)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))[1])]">
```

If you sort this by the number of elements in the group, the first one will give you your maximum.

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="Tree/*[not(self::Break)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::Break)" />

  <xsl:template match="Tree">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::Break)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="count(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break)))" order="descending" />
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break)))" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim C! This is what I need. One last question about the Muenchian Grouping. I'm now trying to get the nodes under each group. I created a foreach to loop the group, but I'm getting the inner label, not the XML node itself. I use `<xsl:value-of select="current()" />`, so I get **Leaf 2**, instead of `<Leaf>
    <Label>Leaf 2</Label>
  </Leaf>`

Comment: You should be using `xsl:copy-of` rather than `xsl:value-of` if you want to preserve the nodes. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwG for an example.